# Wrong dates when loading from s3 to Redshift

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have an automatic process that is loading data from a s3 bucket in parquet format to a table in Redshift. And it was working fine

But now, since 2024, the dates loaded in my redshift table look something like this:
'2377-03-22 02:49:51:703' and before, when it was working fine it looked for example like this: '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000'

I checked the data from my parquet file and the dates are fine, in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'

The code I'm using to load into redshift is a typicall copy_from_files:

```
wr.redshift.copy_from_files(
    path = path,
    con = connection,
    use_threads = True,
    table = table,
    schema = schema,
    mode = 'upsert',
    primary_keys = pks,
    iam_role = ROLE_REDSHIFT,
)
```

The type in the ddl from the redshift table is TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE ENCODE az64

Comment: More info will be needed.  You say that you are loading dates but you are showing timestamps - please share the DDL of the table.  You said that this changed with 2024 but when the data changed to the year 2024 or when your etl changed?  The code you are showing looks to be a python library call, not Redshift statements - can you provide the generated SQL?  What experiments have you tried to narrow down what has changed?

Comment: What do the dates look like in the source file?

Comment: Import it to a string column and make sure the value is actually what you think it is, then do ::timestamp to make sure it converts correctly. Redshift is supposed to play nice with parquet but timestamps can get tricky cause the data type doesn’t really exist in parquet or something.